# Why does Selenium sometimes skip checkboxes?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm having troubles regarding webdriver not being able to click checkboxes sometime and just skipping them, both in Firefox and Chrome.

I've tried different solutions such as

```
click();
action.moveToElement(checkbox).clickAndHold(checkbox).release().perform();
jse.javascriptExecutor(argument[0].click(),checkbox).
```

Here I provide the Javascript code I have for the click event

```
...
var selectCorrectOption = function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $(this).find('> input').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).find('> input').prop('checked', true);

        }
};

$('.option > .input-container').on('click', selectCorrectOption);
...
```

the HTML code where it is attached the javascript click event

```
<div class="input-container selected" data-choice-id="2">
    <input type="radio">
</div>
```

the Java code data uses a data-attribute to access the element is question. Notice also that once the div is clicked, a 'selected' class appears(which is the current state) on the code below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[data-choice-id='"+ wrongOptionVal +"']")));
               radio=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[data-choice-id='"+ wrongOptionVal +"']")));

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", radio);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio);
```

I expected it to be consistent ,most of the times work, but there are always that one or two times it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this happens, I do however know how this can be addressed. You can implement a `FluentWait` with polling mechanism, which will do three things:

- locate the element,
- select the radio box,
- return `getAttribute("class").contains("selected")` value.

If `getAttribute("class").contains("selected")` will result in `false` the process should repeat.

```
    FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(300))
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(radioCssSelector));
            element.click();
            return element.getAttribute("class").contains("selected");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. Apparently the result is always false, so it keeps clicking the checkbox during the 300ms.

Comment: Try it again - I have changed the condition to check if the class contains 'selected'.